# Jquery fill text area with linebreak and nothin if no data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to show JSON data in a `textbox`.
Data is in this format:

```
address{
"street":"1st main Road"
"building_name":"Florence"
"Floor":""
"city":"New York"
}
```

I have tried this:

```
$('#id_address').val(address.street+'\n'+address.building_name+'\n'+address.Floor+'\n'+address.city);
```

But issue is that if there is no data in Floor then there will a linebreak between floor and city. How to avoid line breaks if there is no data in address line?

Comment: Are the property keys known values (i.e. are they always `street`, `building_name`, `Floor`, and `city`)? Are you wanting the values of the properties displayed in a specific order, or will any order work? If you want them in a specific order, then what do you want done with property keys which you have not specified?

Comment: Keys are fixed but order is not proper. Need to do it manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys(address)` to get the keys of the `address` property and loop over that and check if the value is empty or not. Then prepare the value for the `textarea` accordingly based on the condition `address[key] !== ''`. For more perfection use a condition `index+1 !== allKeys.length` to prevent `\n` for the last item.

```js
var address = {
  "street":"1st main Road",
  "building_name":"Florence",
  "Floor":"",
  "city":"New York"
};

var textValue = '';
var allKeys = Object.keys(address);
allKeys.forEach(function(key, index){
  if(address[key] !== ''){
    textValue += address[key];
     if(index+1 !== allKeys.length){
       textValue += '\n';
     }
  }
});
console.log(textValue);
$('#id_address').val(textValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id='id_address' rows='5'></textarea>
```

Comment: @SapnaSharma you can accept the answer if it was helpful to you

Comment: Need to wait for 10 minutes before can accept an answer :)

Comment: SO has time limit of 10 minutes.

Comment: One issue last line has linebreak. How to avoid that?

Comment: @SapnaSharma is that making any difference to your desired output? I mean is it required?

Comment: last line will be `New York /n` and this data will be saved in DB. So when user print address there will be extra space.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171385/discussion-between-ankit-agarwal-and-sapna-sharma).

Answer (score 3):

I know you already accepted an answer, but here is my solution anyway.

I propose you a all-in-one-line solution, not using any loop or something complicated.
Only existing functions/methods, I think that's the easiest solution!… And it's vanilla Javascript!

See comments in my code below:

```js
var address = {
  "street":"1st main Road",
  "building_name":"Florence",
  "Floor":"",
  "city":"New York"
};

// Get values from the object, join them with new lines, and replace the multiple new lines
var textValue = Object.values(address).join('\n').replace(/[\n]+/g, '\n');
// Display in console
console.log(textValue);
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend

```
$('#id_address').val([
  address.street,
  address.building_name,
  address.Floor,
  address.city
].filter(Boolean).join("\n"));
```

or even

```
const keysToShow = ["street", "building_name", "Floor", "city"];
$('#id_address').val(keyToShow.filter(k => k in address).map(k => address[k]).join("\n"));
```

Don't use `Object.keys`, `Object.value` or a `for … in` loop if you want to guaranteed the expected order of the values.

Comment: In my opinion, there is no need to specify an order. Because some information order can differ from a country to another. Plus, if we add another piece of information, the JS code must be changed.

Comment: @TakitIsy I don't see how any of this would be a reason to have no consistent order? Sure, to support multiple countries you might need multiple different orders, but not no order at all. And yes, changing code often requires changes in multiple places, that's how programming works.

Answer (score 1):

I would use append rather than hardcoding it - so in future you can have more values:

Eg:

```
myObj = { "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null };

$.each(myObj,function(data,value){
if (value !== null ) {
    $('#addres').append(data + '-' + value + '<br>');
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  `
var html ='';
if(address.street != ''){
   html = html + address.street +'\n';
}if (address.building_name != ''){
   html = html + address.building_name +'\n';
}if (address.Floor != ''){
   html = html + address.Floor +'\n';
}if (address.city != ''){
   html = html + address.city;
}
$('#id_address').val(html);

`
Try this one
```

Comment: It will not work with `else if`. you should use if only.