# Efficient way to generate all combinations for an address - Javascript

Tags: javascript, string-concatenation, servicenow

Our team wants to generate a concatenated address based on a user's input for street, city, state, and zip.  The issue is many times a user may not fill out all four of these inputs.  Is there a way to efficiently generate all combinations for the concatenated address field without writing 12 if statements?

For example, if a user has all 4 fields filled out, we want to return this:

```
return current.agency_street + ', ' + current.agency_city + ', ' + current.agency_state + ', ' + current.agency_zip;
```

If they have everything filled out except zip code, we want to return this:

```
return current.agency_street + ', ' + current.agency_city + ', ' + current.agency_state;
```

Is there a way to do this without all the if statements?  Thanks!

Comment: not sure what the down vote without a comment is for, but would still love to know if this is possible

Comment: Does your current object only contain those properties?

Comment: How do you know whether your user has input something into them?

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50427492/1048572)

Comment: The implicit not-quite-normal-javascript thing going on here is that `current` is a `GlideRecord` instance. So, dot-walks into fields (eg agency_street) are going to behave a little differently since they are returning GlideElement instances. They will never be null, but concatenating to a string is going to return an empty string if the internal field value is null (otherwise it'll return the toString'd value like you'd expect).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can push all to an array and filter out the falsy values.

```
var values = [];
values.push(agency_street);
values.push(agency_city);
values.push(agency_state);
values.push(agency_zip);
return values.filter(x => x).join(', ');
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xfqumxox/

Comment: Thanks!!  the arrow syntax doesn't work for us, but I used return values.filter(Boolean).join(', '); and it works.  thanks again for this!

Comment: Great! Very good - and I learned something as well about `filter(Boolean)`. So thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As always a loop helps to simplify things:

```
let result = "";
for(const key of ["street", "city", "state", "zip"]) {
  const value = current["agency_" + key];
  if(value) result += (result && ",") + value;
}
return result;
```

Which is maybe a bit more elegant with functional style:

```
return ["street", "city", "state", "zip"].map(key => current["agency_" + key]).filter(Boolean).join(", ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if only the filled in properties of the object are set and the order of the results doesn't strictly matter:

```
Object.keys(current).map(key => current[key]).filter(val => val).join(", ");
```

Comment: This does not guarantee the order of the result

Comment: You're right, if the order strictly matters this answer won't do. I'll update it to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator as well

```
return (current.agency_street ? current.agency_street : '') + (current.agency_city ? ',' + current.agency_city : '') + (current.agency_state ? ',' + current.agency_state : '') + (current.agency_zip ? ',' + current.agency_zip : '');
```

Comment: This might emit a leading comma